# Installing ggplot “subscript out of bounds” error

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
$ R
R version 2.12.2 (2011-02-25)
Platform: i486-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)

> install.packages("ggplot2", dep="T")
Error in apply(available[p1, dependencies, drop = FALSE], 1L, function(x)  paste(x[!is.na(x)],  : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

What can I do to install ggplot2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing ggplot “package ‘ggplot’ is not available” error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522830/installing-ggplot-package-ggplot-is-not-available-error)

Comment: @Mat - no, this is a different error. The OP should have just added to his original Q with a follow up, but this is not the same as the original Q.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing ggplot “package ‘ggplot’ is not available” and “subscript out of bounds” errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522830/installing-ggplot-package-ggplot-is-not-available-and-subscript-out-of-boun)

Comment: I ran into the same problem but it turned out to be caused by a lack of space on my disk. Just wanted to leave this here in case someone runs into the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do read the help for functions! From `?install.packages` we have:

```
dependencies: logical indicating to also install uninstalled packages
          on which these packages depend/suggest/import (and so on
          recursively).  Not used if ‘repos = NULL’.  Can also be a
          character vector, a subset of ‘c("Depends", "Imports",
          "LinkingTo", "Suggests", "Enhances")’.
```

So this clearly states that you need to supply a logical value, a `TRUE` or a `FALSE`. `"T"` is not a logical `TRUE` and neither is `T` really. Always spell out `TRUE` and `FALSE` otherwise you could get into lots of trouble. It isn't worth the hassle to save on a few keystrokes.

As I showed in the answer to the previous Q:

```
R> install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)
```

works. So why did you alter what I showed you did work?

Comment: I was trying to follow the ggplot steps as described here: http://had.co.nz/ggplot/ . You solved one error (package renamed) and I went on because I did not assume there were two errors on the page I was following. When following tutorials I usually assume that the error is in my settings/system, not in the tutorial, that's why it was not the help I was reading. Thanks for the solution and explanation.